# How to change filepath when check a radiobutton? Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, filepath

My problem here is that i have 3 radiobuttons for 3 different categories:
Huse Folii and Altele.

The idea is when i select a radiobutton,the filepath will change to Huse,Folii or Altele.

For example i tried to make _path :

```
Dim _path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Descriere\Huse\")
```

then use the _path here:

```
Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(_path + "a.txt")
```

but it didn't worked,for sure i do something wrong,but i can't find how or where to use that _path...

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    TextBox1.Clear()
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Dim _path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Descriere\Huse\")
    End If
    If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Dim _path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Descriere\Folii\")
    End If
    If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        IO.Path.
        Dim _path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Descriere\Altele\")
    End If

    Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(_path + "a.txt")
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim line As Integer
    While ioFile.Peek <> -1
        lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
    End While
    line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)
    TextBox1.AppendText(lines(line).Trim())
    ioFile.Close()
    ioFile.Dispose()
    Dim ioFile2 As New System.IO.StreamReader(path:=+"core.txt")
    Dim lines2 As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd2 As New Random()
    Dim line2 As Integer
    While ioFile2.Peek <> -1
        lines2.Add(ioFile2.ReadLine())
    End While
    line2 = rnd2.Next(lines2.Count + 1)
    TextBox1.AppendText(lines2(line2).Trim())
    ioFile2.Close()
    ioFile2.Dispose()
    Dim ioFile3 As New System.IO.StreamReader(path:=+"x.txt")
    Dim lines3 As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd3 As New Random()
    Dim line3 As Integer
    While ioFile3.Peek <> -1
        lines3.Add(ioFile3.ReadLine())
    End While
    line3 = rnd3.Next(lines3.Count + 1)
    TextBox1.AppendText(lines3(line3).Trim())
    ioFile3.Close()
    ioFile3.Dispose()
    TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "BRAND", TextBox2.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "MODEL", TextBox3.Text)
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    count = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length - 1
    Label5.Text = "Caractere:" & Len(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go to Help Center > Asking and read the FAQ's. Always add your programming language to your question.

Comment: I changed your vba tag to vb.net and Check-box to radio-button. Please use tags in context.

Answer (score 0):

You are using IO.Path.Combine but you have nothing to Combine at the place of use in your code. You have to use IO.Path.Combine later in your code because this is a method to `Combine` part of a path and a filename e.g. set your `_path` first and combine in a second step. Please note this code is not tested for your needs, because your coding is not clear to me.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim directoryName As String = "D:\"

  On Error Resume Next
  TextBox1.Clear()
  If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
    directoryName = "D:\Descriere\Huse"
  End If
  If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
    directoryName = "D:\Descriere\Folii"
  End If
  If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
    '//--- IO.Path.
    directoryName = "D:\Descriere\Altele"
  End If

  Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, "a.txt"))

...

  Dim ioFile2 As New System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, "core.txt"))

...

  Dim ioFile3 As New System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, "x.txt"))

...

End Sub
```

Please use the debugger of your IDE because your code isn't clean e.g. a hanging aroung `IO.Path.`